# Layout transition between multiple subpasses in Vulkan

Tags: graphics, vulkan

I am trying to do two simple subpasses, where the second one has a dependency on the first one.

```
//subpass 1
VkAttachmentReference colorReferences = { 0, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL };

VkSubpassDescription subpass1 = {};
subpass1.pipelineBindPoint = VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS;
subpass1.pColorAttachments = &colorReferences;
subpass1.colorAttachmentCount = 1;

//subpass 2
VkAttachmentReference inputRefernce = { 0, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL };

VkSubpassDescription subpass2 = {};
subpass2.pipelineBindPoint = VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS;
subpass2.inputAttachmentCount = 1;
subpass2.pInputAttachments = &inputRefernce;

//Render pass
VkAttachmentDescription attachmentDescs = {};
attachmentDescs.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
attachmentDescs.loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR;
attachmentDescs.storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE;
attachmentDescs.stencilLoadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
attachmentDescs.stencilStoreOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
attachmentDescs.format = VK_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_SFLOAT;
attachmentDescs.initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;
attachmentDescs.finalLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;

VkSubpassDependency dependency = {};

dependency.srcSubpass = 0;
dependency.dstSubpass = 1;  
dependency.srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_ALL_GRAPHICS_BIT;
dependency.dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_ALL_GRAPHICS_BIT;
dependency.srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;
dependency.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT;

VkSubpassDescription subpasses[2] = { subpass1, subpass2 };
VkRenderPassCreateInfo renderPassInfo = {};
renderPassInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_CREATE_INFO;
renderPassInfo.pAttachments = &attachmentDescs;
renderPassInfo.attachmentCount = 1;
renderPassInfo.subpassCount = 2;
renderPassInfo.pSubpasses = subpasses;
renderPassInfo.dependencyCount = 1;
renderPassInfo.pDependencies = &dependency;

vkUtils::checkResult(vkCreateRenderPass(_context->device, &renderPassInfo, nullptr, &_renderPass));
```

I have a dependency between the first and the second subpass. The specification says:

> If an attachment specifies the `VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR` load
>   operation, then it will logically be cleared at the start of the first
>   subpass where it is used.

It will only be cleared at the start of the first subpass the attachment is used. And because there is a dependency between them, it should not be cleared in the second subpass.

> The first use of an attachment must not specify a layout equal to
>   VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL or
>   VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL if the attachment specifies
>   that the > loadOp is VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR. [...]

I get this error from the validation layer:

```
Cannot clear attachment 0 with invalid first layout VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL.
```

But the `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL` layout is in the second subpass, not the first one?

Comment: Could you post code that can compile? Because you declared a variable `subpass1`, then talk about an undeclared variable `subpass`.

Comment: That was not the only place. Please copy it directly from your source code.

Comment: done:) but so much for a text, maybe I can shorter it done if a solution is found

Comment: with `VkAttachmentDescription attachmentDescs[5];` you assume your `_attachments.size()` `== 5`

Comment: @NicolBolas I have made the code smaller with only one attachment so it is easier to find the problem.

Comment: @krOoze now its only using one attachment, still the same problem though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in the layers, which simply do not check which usage is first (It was probably introduced in 1.0.17 SDK - 1.0.13 should not report this...):
https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers/blob/sdk-1.0.17/layers/core_validation.cpp#L8557

spec quote:

> The first use of an attachment **must not** specify a layout equal to `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL` or `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL` if the attachment specifies that the `loadOp` is `VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR`. [...]

Comment: It says: the first use use ...., its in the second subpass that I am using VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL, in the first subpass the layout is VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL

Comment: Yeah, the layer does not seem to discriminate the first use (it iterates over all subpasses). I wonder why the `0` attachment didn't get reported though. Does your app work despite the reported errors?

Comment: I have not finish the last part of the application, but I will soon, and maybe its a validation bug:)

Comment: I have already reported it and it's being fixed as we speak: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers/pull/774