# Vulkan input attachment from previous subpass

Tags: vulkan

I am trying to use the color attachment created in subpass 0 as an input attachment in subpass 1. However there is an issue that i cant get past.

My problem currently is the following, i try to clear attachment 0 at the beginning of the pass using `VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR` however gives the error.

```
Cannot clear attachment 0 with invalid first layout VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL.
```

Which seems weird to me, attachment 0 does not get layout `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL` untill subpass 1 where it is a input attachment, while the clear should have already happened when the layout was still `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL` (AFAIK).

I have now tried to just continue running after the validation error, and attachment 0 **does** get cleared, which makes me even more unsure. I can apparently just ignore the validation error, but something weird might be going on that could cause problems later on so I am not confidant enough to just ignore it.

Here is the minimal code that will give the error:

---

```
VkAttachmentDescription attachments[1] {};
attachments[0].format = VK_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_SFLOAT;
attachments[0].samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
attachments[0].loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR;
attachments[0].storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE;
attachments[0].stencilLoadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
attachments[0].stencilStoreOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
attachments[0].initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;
attachments[0].finalLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;

VkAttachmentReference pass_0_ColorAttachments[1];
pass_0_ColorAttachments[0].attachment = 0;
pass_0_ColorAttachments[0].layout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;

VkAttachmentReference pass_1_InputAttachments[1];
pass_1_InputAttachments[0].attachment = 0;
pass_1_InputAttachments[0].layout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL;

VkSubpassDescription subpasses[2] {};

subpasses[0].colorAttachmentCount = 1;
subpasses[0].pColorAttachments = pass_0_ColorAttachments;
subpasses[0].pipelineBindPoint = VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS;

subpasses[1].inputAttachmentCount = 1;
subpasses[1].pInputAttachments = pass_1_InputAttachments;
subpasses[1].pipelineBindPoint = VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS;

VkSubpassDependency subpassDependancies[1] {};
subpassDependancies[0].srcSubpass = 0;
subpassDependancies[0].dstSubpass = 1;
subpassDependancies[0].srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
subpassDependancies[0].dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT;
subpassDependancies[0].srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;
subpassDependancies[0].dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_INPUT_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT;
subpassDependancies[0].dependencyFlags = VK_DEPENDENCY_BY_REGION_BIT;

VkRenderPassCreateInfo renderpassCreateInfo {};
renderpassCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_CREATE_INFO;
renderpassCreateInfo.attachmentCount = 1;
renderpassCreateInfo.pAttachments = attachments;
renderpassCreateInfo.subpassCount = 2;
renderpassCreateInfo.pSubpasses = subpasses;
renderpassCreateInfo.dependencyCount = 1;
renderpassCreateInfo.pDependencies = subpassDependancies;

VkRenderPass renderPass;
vkCreateRenderPass(device, &renderpassCreateInfo, nullptr, &renderPass);
```

---

The next part is only relevant if it is impossible to specify `VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR` for an attachment used as color attachment first and in a later subpass as input attachment (i see no reason why this would be impossible, unless vulkan does the load operation each subpass). So this is kind of a separate problem.

I could, instead of using `VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR`, manually clear the attachment using `vkCmdClearAttachments` and use `VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE` for the load operation of the attachment.

I have a crash error on calling `vkCmdClearAttachments`
I started the command buffer recording and the renderpass, and in the first subpass I call:

`VkClearAttachment clearAtts[] = {{VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT, 1, {0,0,0,0}}};
VkClearRect rect = {{{0,0}, {1,1}}, 0, 1};
vkCmdClearAttachments(vkCommandBuffer, 1, clearAtts, 1, &rect);`

{1,1} as the extent to show this is not the problem

Comment: "*And then changing the layout between the subpasses with a barrier. [...] But it seems I HAVE to use these different layouts for vulkan to even accept the renderpass creation.*" I don't quite understand that. You can't put a pipeline barrier in renderpass creation. You can (and have to) create a subpass dependency. But that's different from a pipeline barrier. So which one are you talking about?

Comment: I edited the question, I think it should be clear this way. In short:
I use different layouts for the discriptions of the input and color attachment of the respective subpasses pointing to the same image. And thus later a barrier is needed to change the layout.

Comment: That didn't clear it up. When you say "forcing me to later use a barrier to switch the layout", do you mean a `vkCmdPipelineBarrier`, or do you mean a `VkSubpassDependency`? If it's the latter, then show us what that dependency looks like.

Comment: A subpass dependency is allready in place aswell (the validation layers tell you to use this). But i mean the `vkCmdPipelineBarrier` to change layout between subpasses.

Comment: If you have a subpass dependency in place, and you have given it the correct values, that will do your layout transition for you, so you don't need a barrier: "The implementation will automatically perform layout transitions as needed between subpasses to make each subpass use the requested layouts." So please show us the subpass dependency code.

Comment: Indeed, you need to show us *everything* you pass to `vkCreateRenderPass`. The error you say the validation layer is giving you shouldn't happen unless you've done something wrong somewhere. And where that is isn't in code you've shown us.

Comment: Ah that about the dependency taking care of the layout conversion was indeed something i missed. 
So now the main problem is what VkAttachmentLoadOp to use so the attachment gets cleared on start of subpass 0. And you mean that the error about the clear op should not appear?
I will extend the question as you asked tomorrow.

Comment: I added the code you requested

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're having the same problem [as was discovered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38445001/layout-transition-between-multiple-subpasses-in-vulkan). It's a bug in the validation layer in 1.0.17. It would appear that the [current Github head](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers/blob/master/layers/core_validation.cpp#L8957) has a fix, but that fix is not in the 1.0.21 release.

But you *still* need to fix the stuff below ;)

---

> ```
> subpassDependancies[0].dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT | VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT;
> ```

You are not going to read the image as a color attachment. You're going to read it as an input attachment. From the fragment shader. So that would mean `VK_ACCESS_INPUT_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT`.

If that fixes the error, then I'd guess the validation layer got confused by your oddball dependency access mask. It therefore couldn't establish a valid dependency chain between subpasses 0 and 1, and thus thought that subpass 1 was first.

Also, your `srcStageMask` and `dstStageMask` bits are *way* over-specified. Every graphics stage is not going to write to the image, and every graphics stage is not going to access it after. You only wrote to the image as a color attachment, and you're only going to read from it in the fragment shader.

So your `srcStageMask` ought to just be `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT`, and your `dstStageMask` ought to be `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT`.

Comment: Using the changes you suggested has no effect on the error. Is there any chance this could be a driver bug? I'm using a firepro m2000 (HD Radeon 7700M series, vulkan 1.0.17)

Comment: @BartVerberne: It's an error from a validation layer. Those are never part of the driver.

Comment: I have made the question clearer, also the clear operation actually does work if i continue after the error (i used to halt my program on validation errors because usually this would case a near immediate crash)